# ¿Como puedo solucionar este problema en Spring boot + JPA + Bootstrap + mysql

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

Saludos comunidad tengo el siguiente código y me genera el error si alguien 
de la comunidad tiene conocimiento a que se debe el error 
muchas gracias

en el Controller.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/agregar",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String direccionForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("direccion",new Direccion());
        model.addAttribute("usuarios", usuarioService.usuarioLista());
        return "direccion/lista";
    }

@GetMapping("/lista")
    public String direccionLista(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("direcciones",direccionService.direccionLista());
        return "direccion/lista";

    }

@PostMapping("/agregar")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin')")
    public String agregarDireccion(@Valid @ModelAttribute("direccion") Direccion direccion,Model model,BindingResult bindingResult){

        String mensaje="";
        if(direccion.getId()==null || bindingResult.hasErrors() ){
            mensaje="agregado";
        } 

        else{
            mensaje="actualizado";
        }

        model.addAttribute("mensaje", direccionService.agregarDireccion(direccion).getUsuario().getUsuarioNombre()+"direccion"+mensaje+"direccion agregado...");
        return "mensaje";

    }
```

en el jsp.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<c:set var="path" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"></c:set>
<html>
<head>
<%@include file="/template/header.jsp"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="${path}/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script  type="text/javascript"  src="${path}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script    type="text/javascript"  src="${path}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>          
            <script   type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/popper.min.js"></script>  

            <script   type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/main1.js"></script>

<%-- <script   type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/main.js"></script> --%>




<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>
<br>





    <div class="container">
         <button  class="btn btn-primary nBtn" >Nuevo</button>
          <br>
          <br>
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">

    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Ciudad</th>
                <th>Distrito</th>
                <th>Pais</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Actualizar</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>   
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${direcciones}" var="direccion">
                <tr>
                    <td>${direccion.ciudad}</td>
                    <td>${direccion.distrito}</td>
                    <td>${direccion.pais}</td>
                    <td>${direccion.usuario.usuarioNombre}</td>
                    <td><a href="${path}/direccion/actualizar/${direccion.id}" class="btn btn-primary eBtn">Actualizar</a></td>
                    <td><a href="${path}/direccion/eliminar/${direccion.id}"  class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a></td>
                </tr>

            </c:forEach>

        </tbody>



    </table>
    </div>
    </div>

  <div class="myForm">

<!--  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Agregar Direccion</button> -->

    <form:form  action="${path}/direccion/agregar" method="post" modelAttribute="direccion"  >
        <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" 
        tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Actualizar o Guardar</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pais" class="col-form-label">Pais:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pais" name="pais" value=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ciudad" class="col-form-label">Ciudad:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad" name="ciudad"  value=""/>
                  </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="distrito" class="col-form-label">Distrito:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="distrito" name="distrito" value=""/>
                  </div>
                  <p>Usuario :</p>
                <form:select path="usuario.id">
                <c:forEach items="${usuarios}" var="usuario">
                    <form:option value="${usuario.id}">${usuario.usuarioNombre}</form:option>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>  
        <p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="guardar"/>
              </div>
        </div>

          </div>

        </div>
        </form:form>
      </div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

en js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.nBtn, .table .eBtn').on('click',function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        var href=$(this).attr('href');
        var text=$(this).text();
        if(text=='Actualizar'){}
        $.get(href,function(direccion,status){
            $('.myForm #ciudad').val(direccion.ciudad);
            $('.myForm #distrito').val(direccion.distrito);
            $('.myForm #pais').val(direccion.ciudad);
            $('.myForm #usuario').val(direccion.usuario.usuarioNombre);
        });

        $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();

    }else{
        $('.myForm #ciudad').val(direccion.ciudad);
        $('.myForm #distrito').val(direccion.distrito);
        $('.myForm #pais').val(direccion.ciudad);

        $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();
    }
    });
});
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'direccion' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:173) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:193) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:159) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:345) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:86) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.jsp.vista.direccion.lista_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(lista_jsp.java:821) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.vista.direccion.lista_jsp._jspService(lista_jsp.java:419) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.ventura.app.filter.CustomFilter.doFilter(CustomFilter.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.ventura.app.filter.CustomFilter.doFilter(CustomFilter.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola tienes que agregar `model.addAttribute("direccion",new Direccion());` ya que en tu jsp listar tienes un form que requiere ese objecto en tu modelo `modelAttribute="direccion"`.

```
@GetMapping("/lista")
public String direccionLista(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("direcciones",direccionService.direccionLista());
    model.addAttribute("direccion",new Direccion());
    return "direccion/lista";

}
```