# Como puedo solucionar este problema en spring boot + bootstrap + jsp

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

Saludos tengo el problema estoy utilizando spring boot y bootstrap v4  por lo cual quiero mostrar un combito que me muestre los datos en un formulario pero no me muestra dejo el código correspondiente y ademas solucione el error que publique anteriormente en esta comunidad dejo también el link.
 [¿Como puedo solucionar este problema en Spring boot + JPA + Bootstrap + mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175470/como-puedo-solucionar-este-problema-en-spring-boot-jpa-bootstrap-mysql).

En el **controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/lista")
public String direccionLista(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("direcciones",direccionService.direccionLista());
    return "direccion/lista";

}


@PostMapping("/agregar")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin')")
public String agregarDireccion(@ModelAttribute("direccion") Direccion direccion,Model model,BindingResult bindingResult)throws IOException {



    String mensaje="";
    if(direccion.getId()==null ){
        mensaje="agregado";
    } 
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){

    }

    else{
        mensaje="actualizado";
    }

    model.addAttribute("mensaje", direccionService.agregarDireccion(direccion).getUsuario().getUsuarioNombre()+"direccion"+mensaje+"direccion agregado...");
    return "redirect:/direccion/lista";

}
```

En el **jsp:**

```
<div class="container">
<br>
     <button  class="btn btn-primary nBtn" >Nuevo</button>
      <br>
      <br>
<div class="card">
<div class="card-block">

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Codigo</th>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Distrito</th>
            <th>Pais</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Actualizar</th>
            <th>Eliminar</th>   
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${direcciones}" var="direccion">
            <tr>
                <td>${direccion.id}</td>
                <td>${direccion.ciudad}</td>
                <td>${direccion.distrito}</td>
                <td>${direccion.pais}</td>
                <td>${direccion.usuario.usuarioNombre}</td>
                <td><a href="${path}/direccion/actualizar/${direccion.id}" class="btn btn-primary eBtn">Actualizar</a></td>
                <td><a href="${path}/direccion/eliminar/${direccion.id}"  class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a></td>
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>

    </tbody>



</table>
</div>
</div>
```

```
<form:form  action="${path}/direccion/lista" method="post"  modelAttribute="direcciones" >

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" 
    tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Actualizar o Guardar</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id" class="col-form-label">Codigo:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value=""/>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pais" class="col-form-label">Pais:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pais" name="pais" value=""/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ciudad" class="col-form-label">Ciudad:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad" name="ciudad"  value=""/>
              </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                <label for="distrito" class="col-form-label">Distrito:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="distrito" name="distrito" value=""/>
              </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="usuario" class="col-form-label">Usuario:</label>

                    <select name="usuario.id" id="usuario">
                        <c:forEach items="${usuarios}" var="usuario" >
                            <option value="${usuario.id}">${usuario.usuarioNombre}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>   
                </div>



         </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="guardar"/>
          </div>
    </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    </form:form>
  </div>
```

En el **main1 script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.nBtn, .table .eBtn').on('click',function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    var text=$(this).text();

    if(text=='Actualizar' && document.getElementById("usuario").value != "none"){ 
         var usuario = document.getElementById('usuario').value;

    $.get(href,function(direccion,usuario,status){
        $('.myForm #id').val(direccion.id);
        $('.myForm #ciudad').val(direccion.ciudad);
        $('.myForm #distrito').val(direccion.distrito);
        $('.myForm #pais').val(direccion.ciudad);
        $('.myForm #usuario').val(usuario.nombre);
    });

    $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();

}else{

    $('.myForm #id').val('');
    $('.myForm #ciudad').val('');
    $('.myForm #distrito').val('');
    $('.myForm #pais').val('');
    $('.myForm #usuario').val('');

    $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();
}

});
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Usas una lista de usuarios (asumo) llamada `usuarios`... ¿pero dónde se la pasas al JSP?

Comment: exacto  en el JSP esta contenido un Modal en Boostrap v4 ese modal tiene un combito que me  tiene mostrar los nombres de los usuarios que se encuentra en una base de datos mysql pero no me muestra no se a que se debe

Comment: Pues creo que por lo que te digo: nunca añades a model la lista de usuarios

Comment: @PabloLozano ¿Quizás eso debería ser una respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en ningún momento has añadido la lista de usuarios al modelo, tienes dos métodos que llaman a

```
model.addAttribute("<clave>", valor);
```

Pero en ninguno de los dos casos la clave es `"usuarios"`, por tanto no existe esa lista que intentas recorrer en tu bucle.

Comment: Es cierto gracias

Answer (score 1):

tenia que cambiar en el controller las siguientes lineas de codigo:

```
@GetMapping("/lista")
public String direccionLista(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("direcciones",direccionService.direccionLista());
    model.addAttribute("usuarios",usuarioService.usuarioLista());
    return "direccion/lista";

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]